# Bound DropDownList with AppendDataBoundItems not returning Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, entitydatasource

I have this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="HomeCountry" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="CountryListEntityDS" 
    DataTextField="CountryNameEn" 
    DataValueField="CountryCode" 
    AppendDataBoundItems="True"                          
    SelectedValue="<%# Bind('HomeCountry') %>">                                              
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and the datasource is like this:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="CountryListEntityDS" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=MainDataModelEntityCont" 
        DefaultContainerName="MainDataModelEntityCont" 
        EnableFlattening="False" 
        EntitySetName="Countries">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

I get the drop down with the countries and the --- Select One --- as the first item correctly.  Everything work correctly EXCEPT when I change a record that had a country to the --- select one --- (so not having a country) and press save.

Then it throws:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): The UPDATE statement conflicted with the
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Account_CountryList".

I have reproduced this error manually in SQL Server Management Studio, it occurs if I try to change a record's Country field from a valid value to a "".  The same error is thrown.  But when I put Null it works fine.  The DB constraint is basically saying you have to have either a valid value or Null.

So it seems to me, the C# code somehow is not resulting in a Null being sent to DB, rather a blank string.

Anyone help greatly appreciated.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a problem with your sql query. look into the query and the table fields, specially the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a default value for country(e.g US).
or you can have a value like 0 in DB for countries that is not seleceted by users so when the value of dropdown is "" you can send 0 to DB for updating table.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The data type on the SQL table makes the difference.

(TextBox has similar behaviour.)

It seems the rule is, when the server control is bound to a database field that can accept a blank string (ie: "") it returns that to db, on save.  But when it is bound to a type that cannot, it returns Null.

Hence for my problem above, it was solved when I changed from char(2) to int for the country code.  The Null did not violate the foreign key constraint, while "" did.